# How can I use Opus-Codec in my Java Application

Tags: codec, speech, speex

I read a lot about opus-codec but I am not understanding how can I use that in my sample java application.
Is there any .so file available for opus which can be used?If not then how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently not yet (at time of writing) any native Java library for Opus.

The [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org) project is a Java-based VOIP and chat client which has Opus support. This is implemented by using a binary libopus library with a [Java wrapper](https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi/search?q=opus&ref=cmdform).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to create a wrapper around libopus that you can call from Java. I have done something like that in C#: http://opusdotnetinvoke.codeplex.com/
It should be easy to rewrite that C# code into Java.